# Can a jQuery anchor class element be pulled in using .load()?

Tags: jquery

I'm using `.load()` to bring in text from one page to another.  One particular div I'm 'loading' has a modal triggered by an anchor class. However, that anchor class does not function after being 'loaded.'  Is there any way around this?

I posted a simple example here: http://temp.kissr.com/

You can see that nothing happens when clicked.  However, this is the page where the green box and accompanying alert is being pulled in from: http://temp.kissr.com/div_being_loaded.html

View the source on these pages to check my .load() method. My approach is also posted here:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#grab_div').load('div_being_loaded.html .load');
    }); 
</script>

<div id="grab_div"></div>
```

And this is the div that's being loaded from a separate page (div_being_loaded.html), but located at the same root level.

```
<div class="load">
    <a class="alert">Click for Alert</a>
</div>

<script>
    $("a.alert").on("click", function() {
        alert( "Success" );
    });
</script>
```

Thank you for taking a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your click event binding is made before the content is present inside the DOM. You have 2 solutions.

1) You could wait for the content to be loaded :

```
$(function() {
    $('#grab_div').load('div_being_loaded.html .load', function(){
        $("a.alert").on("click", function() {
            alert( "Success" );
        });
    });
});
```

2) or you can use event delegation :

```
$("#grab_div").on("click", 'a.alert', function() {
    alert( "Success" );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
$('#grab_div').load('div_being_loaded.html .load');
```

with

```
$('#grab_div').load('div_being_loaded.html');
```

(Or you have you place the whole `script` block inside your `<div class="load">`.)

By adding the `.load` (from `<div class="load">`) class you are only loading in that bit of the HTML and not the `script` block.